# инициализация полей класса

Tags: c++

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00E34DF3 в kyrsovui.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000.

Проблема: не заполняется двумерный динамический массив в конструкторе класса.
выполнял пошагово - массив создается, вроде бы нормально заполняется,
но сразу же после выходи из цикла заполнения если посмотреть на элемент то =???

```
class Pole
{
    public:
    int **main_mas;
    sf::Texture texture1;
    sf::Texture texture2;
    sf::Sprite sprite1;
    sf::Sprite sprite2;

    Pole();
    ~Pole();
    void draw_grid(sf::RenderWindow *);
    void draw_mas(sf::RenderWindow *);
};


Pole::Pole(){
    int **main_mas=new int *[20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        main_mas[i]=new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        for(int w=0;w<10;w++)
            main_mas[i][w]=1;
    texture1.loadFromFile("images/square.png");
    sprite1.setTexture(texture1);
    texture2.loadFromFile("images/square_blue.png");
    sprite2.setTexture(texture2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну классика. Вы объявили локальную переменную и туда записали указатель. int из первой строчки конструктора устраните.

Answer (score 1):

В конструкторе вы создаете массивы и присваиваете адрес первого массива локальной переменной `main_mas`  вместо использования члена класса с таким же именем

```
Pole::Pole(){
    int **main_mas=new int *[20];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Поэтому член класса у вас остается неинициализированным, а в программе происходит утечка памяти.

В принципе нет никакой необходимости создавать динамически массив такой небольшой размерности. Вы могли бы объявить массив как член класса вместо указателя

```
class Pole
{
    public:
    int main_mas[20][10];
    //...
```

Также желательно не использовать магические числа типа 20, а присваивать им имена.

Например, вы могли бы добавить в класс перечисление

```
class Pole
{
//...
private:
    enum { N = 20, M = 10 };
    //...
```

и использовать перечислители `N` и `M` везде, где вам придется ссылаться на размеры массива.

Вместо перечисления вы также можете использовать константные статические члены данных:

```
class Pole
{
//...
private:
    const static size_t N = 20;
    const static size_t M = 10;
    //...
```